# Copying the files from google drive to our server via Google Drive PHP library API V3

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, google-drive-realtime-api

I'm trying to integrate Google Drive within our website. What we would like to do is to copy a file from Drive to our server, you know, kind of : Send to My Files. When i try to integrate i am facing the following error

[image]

**My tried code:**

```
require_once(ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'google-api-php-client' . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'autoload.php');

        define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'Drive API PHP Quickstart');
        define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS. 'google-api-php-client' . DS .'vendor' . DS . 'drive-php-quickstart.json');
        define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS. 'google-api-php-client' . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'client_secret.json');
        define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(\Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY)));


        $client = new \Google_Client();
        $client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
        $client->setScopes(SCOPES);
        $client->setAuthConfig(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
        $client->setAccessType('offline');

        // Load previously authorized credentials from a file.
        $credentialsPath = $this->expandHomeDirectory(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
        if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
            $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($credentialsPath), true);
        } else {
            // Request authorization from the user.
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            print 'Enter verification code: ';
            $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);

            // Store the credentials to disk.
            if (!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
                mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 0700, true);
            }
            file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($accessToken));
            printf("Credentials saved to %s\n", $credentialsPath);
        }
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);


        // Refresh the token if it's expired.
        if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
            file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You error `Notice: Use of undefined constant STDIN` means it was looking for constant called STDIN. When it doesn't find such a constant, PHP interprets it as a string. Obviously, this can easily break if you do defined such a constant later. It stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2941174/5832311) that you should quote your array key to avoid such error. The error message is due to the unfortunate fact that PHP will implicitly declare an unknown token as a constant string of the same name. You may also check on this link: [Copy a file from Google Drive to my own server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11627433/copy-a-file-from-google-drive-to-my-own-server)